# Precision lost in float value using java

Tags: java, floating-point

Given below the test code and its output. When I get float value from number value, precision is lost.. Can anyone tell me why this behaviour and also how to handle this?

```
public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            java.lang.Number numberVal = 676543.21;
            float floatVal = numberVal.floatValue();
            System.out.println("Number value    : " + numberVal);
            System.out.println("float value     : " + floatVal);
            System.out.println("Float.MAX_VALUE : " + Float.MAX_VALUE);
            System.out.println("Is floatVal > Float.MAX_VALUE ? " + ( floatVal > Float.MAX_VALUE));
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

output:

```
    Number value    : 676543.21
    float value     : 676543.2
    Float.MAX_VALUE : 3.4028235E38
    Is floatVal > Float.MAX_VALUE ? false
```

also  why the float value lesser than Float.MAX_VALUE?

Comment: 676543.2 < 3.4028235E38 =  340,282,350,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I love these. But I'll make it quick and painless.

Floats and decimals (aka floating points) aren't kept in the memory precisely either. But I don't want to get into float accuracy vs precision issues here, i'll just point you to a link - http://www.cygnus-software.com/papers/comparingfloats/comparingfloats.htm

As far as your other question, lemme put it this way, since floats are stored in scientific notation.

```
floatVal = 6.765432E6 = 6.7 * 10^6
MAX_VALUE = 3.4E38 = 3.4 * 10^38
```

MAX_VALUE is 32 orders of magnitude bigger than your float number. Feel free to take a look at here as well http://steve.hollasch.net/cgindex/coding/ieeefloat.html

I've spent a great deal of time comparing and fixing some FP issues a few months ago...

Try to use a small delta when comparing floats.
Maybe this link will help you http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/91float/

Answer (score 26):

`float`s are usually good up to 6 significant digits. Your number is `676543.21` which has 8 significant digits. You *will* see errors past 6 digits, and those errors will easily propagate to more significant digits the more calculations you perform. If you value your sanity (or precision), use `double`s. Floats can't even count past 10 million accurately.

Now, you have 2 significant digits, which suggests to me that there is a chance you want to represent currency - *DO NOT* . Use your own class that internally represents values using fixed-point arithmetic.

Now, as to `Float.MAX_VAL` which is 3.4028235E38, meaning 3.4028235*10^38 which is about 10^32 times larger than your value. Notice the 'E' in there? That's the exponent.

Answer (score 9):

All data types have representation limits so the fact there is a limit shouldn't be surprising.

`float` uses 24-bit for its "mantissa" which holds all the significant digits. This means it has about 7 digits of precision (as 2^^24 is about 16 million)

`double` uses 53-bit for it "mantissa" so it can hold about 16 digits accurately.

Comment: This is the simplest, most straight-forward explanation I've found. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

3.4028235E38 is greater than 676543.2. Float.MAX_VALUE is the largest float that is possible to represent.

Comment: Yes, note the `E` in the output!

Answer (score 1):

Decimal literals like the one you have typed default to type `double`, not `float`. java.lang.Number also uses doubles by default. If you were to replace that with `java.lang.Number numberVal = 676543.21f;` I would expect the same level of precision loss from both. Alternatively, replace `float floatVal = numberVal.floatValue();` with `double doubleVal = numberVal.doubleValue();` In order not to lose precision.

EDIT, as an example, try running:

```
Number num = 676543.21;
System.out.println(num); //676543.21
System.out.println(num.doubleValue()); //676543.21
System.out.println(num.floatValue()); //676543.2 <= loses the precision
```

to see the difference in precision of the types

`Float.MAX_VALUE` returns the largest value that a float can ever hold. any higher will overflow. If you look carefully, you'll see an 'E' in its textual representation. This is standard index form, that 'E' means "multiply by 10 to the power of whatever number follows the E" (or in java-speak *pow(10, numberAfterE))

Comment: Not really, `676543.21` can't be represented as a double either.

Comment: @assylias yes really. try 
    Number num = 676543.21;
    System.out.println(num);
    System.out.println(num.doubleValue());
    System.out.println(num.floatValue());
And you will see the loss of precision that is being commented on.

Comment: This is the actual value of `646543.21d`: `646543.209999999962747097015380859375`

Comment: `println` rounds the numbers before printing them - so it's not a reliable way to check. Try `System.out.println(new BigDecimal(646543.21d));` to see the real value.

Comment: the point that I believe the OP was making about precision loss is that as a float the '1' at the end gets dropped

Comment: Yes but I'm saying that using double "in order not to lose precision" is not true - it will increase precision, but it will still be still inexact. Also note that the float is printed as 676543.2 but its real value is 646543.1875.

Comment: "java.lang.Number also uses doubles by default." No it doesn't. *Java* uses doubles by default, unless you suffix 'f' to the numeric literal.