# Convert string to float without round off java

Tags: java, android

I want to convert longitude and latitude that I get as a string from my database. The string is correct, and when i try to convert it into double, it is also correct. However when i am convert the double or the string value (i have tried both) into a float value, the last decimal gets round off.

The value of the string or double is 59.858139
The convertion to float is 59.85814

I've tried everything, and this is one desperate example :)

```
private float ConvertToFloat(double d)
{
    float f = 00.000000f;
    f = (float) d;
    return f;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are starting with your decimal number `59.858139`

Convert that number to binary: `111011.11011011101011101111111101011100011011000001000110100001000100...`

I.e. the number is an infinite fraction in binary. It is not possible to represent it exactly. (In the same way that it is not possible to represent 1/3 exactly with decimal numbers)

Rewrite the number to some form of binary scientific notation:

`10 ^ 101 * 1.1101111011011101011101111111101011100011011000001000110100001000100...`

Remember that this is still in binary, so the `10 ^ 101` corresponds to `2 ^ 5` in decimal notation.

Now... A float value can store 23 bits in the mantissa. If we round it up using "round to nearest" rounding mode, we get:

`10 ^ 101 * 1.11011110110111010111100`

Which is equal to:

`111011.110110111010111100`

That is all the precision that can fit into the float data type. Now convert that back to decimal:

`59.8581390380859375`

Seems pretty close to 59.858139 actually... But that is just luck. What happens if we convert the second closest float value to binary instead?

`111011.110110111010111011 = 59.858135223388671875`

So basically the resolution is approximately `0.000004`.

So all we can really know from the float value is that the number is something like: `59.858139` ± `0.000002`

It could just as well be `59.858137` or `59.858141`.

Since the last digit is rather uncertain, I am guessing that the printing code is smart enough to understand that the last digit falls outside the precision of a float value, and hence, the value is rounded to `59.85814`.

---

By the way, if you (like me are) are too lazy to convert between binary and decimal fractions by hand, you can use [this converter](http://www.exploringbinary.com/binary-converter/). If you want to read more about the details of the floating point system, [the wikipedia page for floating point representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format) is  a great resource.

Comment: Please use IEEE754 instead of binary mathematics ;) also, there's this http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: @Shark the purpose was not to convert the decimal value to floating point representation. His program already does that. The point was to illustrate that the number is an infinite fraction in binary, and hence impossible to represent exactly, no matter what precision is used.

Answer (score 7):

You are aware that doubles have more precision than floats and that floats round off, right? This is expected behaviour. There is no sense in casting a double to a float in this case.

Here's something to get you thinking in the right direction...

```
    Double.doubleToRawLongBits(long value);
    Float.intBitsToFloat(int bits);
```

Doubles can't fit into int and they have to fit into long. It's really twice the size, even mediating bits with strings won't do any good here.

Comment: Yes, but why does the float round off when i convert it from a string? Shouldn't it be the exact value as the string? The double convertion was just something i tried because the string convertion didn't work.

Comment: Float is 32 bits long, Double is 64 bits. The string is a string of characters. 32 bits aren't big enough to represent what you want (the string).

Comment: Take a look at this thread, it covers precision loss of floats http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11825719/precision-lost-in-float-value-using-java/11825865#11825865

Comment: @user1587158: it is _impossible_ to store the exact value you want in a `float`, no matter what parsing or rounding algorithm you use.  That's the point.

Answer (score 3):

**1.** `float` has only **24 bits of precision**, which will be **insufficient** to hold the number of digits in your latitude and longitude.

**2.** The rounding off is due to the size of the number. So use `double` if you require floating point, or use `BigDecimal`

Comment: I'd recommend BigDecimals where doubles don't do the job, in a similar fashion like floats don't here.