# Bijection between Java float and integer keeping order

Tags: java, casting, int

Both `int` and `float` in Java are 32 bits size values. Is it possible to program a pair of functions

```
int toInt(float f);
float toFloat(int n);
```

such that if `f1` and `f2` are arbitrary `float`  non-NaN values and i1 and i2 are arbitraty `int` values:

- `f1 < f2` if and only if `toInt(f1) < toInt(f2)`
- `f1 > f2` if and only if `toInt(f1) > toInt(f2)`
- `f1 == f2` if and only if `toInt(f1) == toInt(f2)`
- `toInt(toFloat(i1) == i1`
- `toFloat(toInt(f1)) == f1`

Edit: I have edited the question to exclude NaN values for float, thanks to the answers clarifying what happens with those.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. [IEEE floats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) and doubles are arranged in such a way that you can compare them by doing an ***unsigned*** comparison of the raw binary representation. The function to convert from float to raw integer and back are [java.lang.Float.floatToIntBits](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#floatToIntBits(float)) and [java.lang.Float.intBitsToFloat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#intBitsToFloat(int)). These functions are processor intrinsics, so they have an extremely low cost.

The same is true for longs and doubles. Here the conversion functions are [java.lang.Double.doubleToLongBits](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#doubleToLongBits(double)) and [java.lang.Double.longBitsToDouble](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#longBitsToDouble(long)).

Note that if you want to use the normal ***signed*** comparison for your integers, you have to do some additional transformation in addition to the conversion to integer.

The only exception to this rule is NaN, which does not permit a total ordering anyway.

Comment: A signed comparison on `x ^ Integer.MIN_VALUE` with `y ^ Integer.MIN_VALUE` is equivalent to an unsigned comparison of `x` and `y`.

Answer (score 1):

I see what you're saying. At first I had a different interpretation of your question. As everyone else has mention: yes. Use the articles described [here](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2006/08/12/floating_point_approximation/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088216/whats-wrong-with-using-to-compare-floats-in-java) to explain why we should use the methods described by @Peter Lawrey in order to compare the underlying bit pattern between ints and floats

Comment: comparing floats via == is a beginners' mistake, this check will never return true.

Comment: yep, they should use the method described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088216/whats-wrong-with-using-to-compare-floats-in-java

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
int n = Float.floatToRawIntBits(f);

float f2 = Float.intBitToFloat(n);

int n2 = Float.floatToRawIntBits(f2);

assert n == n2; // always
assert f == f2 || Float.isNaN(f);
```

The raw bits as a `int` have the same sort order as the original `float` with the exception of the `NaN` values which are not comparable as a `float` value have a value as an `int`

Note: there is multiple values for `NaN` which are not equal to each other as `float`

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot

There are 2^32 possible int values, all of which are distinct.
However, thee are less than 2^32 floats; ie. 7FF0000000000001 to 7FF7FFFFFFFFFFFF represent NaN's,

There fore, you have more ints than floats an cannot distinctly map them to each other as `toFloat(i1)` would not be cable of producing a distinct float for every int

Comment: Technically there is multiple NaN values so the `int` in this range is preserved even if there is no way to tell as `float` values.

Answer (score 1):

The answer from Rüdiger Klaehn gives the normal case, but it lacks some details. The bijection exits only in the domain of *nice and clean* floats.

Notice : representation of an IEEE float is `sign_bit(1 bit) exponent(8 bits) sinificand(23 bits)` and the value is : `(-1)<sup>sign</sup> * 2<sup>exp</sup> * significand` in *clean* cases. In fact, the 23 bits represent the fractional part of the actual significand, the integer part being 1.

All is fine for `0 < exp < 255` (which correspond to *normal* not null floats ) as an unsigned byte and in that domain you have a bijection.

For `exp == 255` you have the infinite values is `significand == 0` and all the NaN for `significand != 0` - ok, you explicitely excluded them.

But for `exp == 0` there are still weird things : when `significand == 0` you have +0 and -0. I am not sure if they are considered equal. If anybody knows, please feel free to edit the post. But as integer values, they will of course be different.

And when `exp == 0` and `significand != 0` you find denormalized numbers ... which while not being equal will be converted to either 0 of the littlest number not being 0.

So if you want a bijection only use *normal* numbers having `0 < exp < 255<` and avoid NaN, infinite, 0 and denormal numbers where things *are* weird.

References :

- [IEEE floating point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point)
- [Single-precision floating-point format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_precision_floating-point_format)
- [Denormal number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormal_numbers)

Answer (score 0):

```
f1 == f2
```

is impossible, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11825865/351861) for more info. You will need to include a delta if you actually want to APPROXIMATE your equality-check.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers contain all the information required to solve this, but not a full solution. Here is some working code you can copy:

```
  public static long toLong(float v) {
    long bits = Integer.toUnsignedLong(Float.floatToIntBits(v));
    return Math.copySign(1, v) < 0 ? -bits : bits;
  }
```

or as a one-liner:

```
(long) Math.copySign((double) Integer.toUnsignedLong(Float.floatToIntBits(v)), v);
```

It should take less than a minute to confirm that this works by iterating every non-NaN float value:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    float current = Float.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
    while (current != Float.POSITIVE_INFINITY) {
      float next = Math.nextUp(current);
      long curLong = toLong(current);
      long nextLong = toLong(next);
      if (curLong >= nextLong) {
        throw new RuntimeException(curLong + " is greater than " + nextLong
            + " representations of " + current + " and " + next);
      }
      current = next;
    }
    System.out.println("Reached " + current);
  }
```