# string parsing to float in java

Tags: java, android, string

I have a string something like this

```
String str = "1432.768641f";
```

I want to parse it to float

I've done something like this

```
float xAxis = Float.valueOf(str);
```

it returns
**1432.7687**
but my expected ans is **1432.768641**

is it possible to get such result without roundup ?. Any help will be appreciated

**I need this result for this.**

```
    package com.view9.stoddart.opengl;

import android.content.Context;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import android.util.FloatMath;
import android.view.MotionEvent;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.DoubleBuffer;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
import java.nio.ShortBuffer;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

public class StoddartRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {
    private Context mContext;
    private DoubleBuffer mVertexBuffer = null;
    private ShortBuffer mTriangleBorderIndicesBuffer = null;
    private int mNumOfTriangleBorderIndices = 0;

    public float mAngleX = 0.0f;
    public float mAngleY = 0.0f;
    public float mAngleZ = 0.0f;
    private float mPreviousX;
    private float mPreviousY;
    private final float TOUCH_SCALE_FACTOR = 0.6f;
    int pointers = 0;
    float distance = 1;
    RenderListener renderListener;

    public void setRenderListener(RenderListener renderListener) {
        this.renderListener = renderListener;
    }


    public StoddartRenderer(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
        gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();

        gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, -3.0f);
        gl.glRotatef(mAngleX, 1, 0, 0);
        gl.glRotatef(mAngleY, 0, 1, 0);
        gl.glRotatef(mAngleZ, 0, 0, 1);

        gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, mVertexBuffer);

        // Set line color to green
         gl.glColor4f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

        // Draw all lines
        gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_LINES, mNumOfTriangleBorderIndices,
                GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, mTriangleBorderIndicesBuffer);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig config) {
        gl.glClearColor(1f, 1f, 1f, 1);
        gl.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL10.GL_NICEST);
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);

        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

        // Get all the buffers ready
        setAllBuffers();
    }

    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
        if (height == 0) height = 1;
        gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
        float aspect = (float) width / height;
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
//        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        gl.glFrustumf(-aspect, aspect, -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    }

    private void setAllBuffers() {
        ArrayList<CoOrdinatesModel> cordinateList = new ArrayList<>();

        cordinateList.add(new CoOrdinatesModel(0.0, 0.0, 0.0));
        cordinateList.add(new CoOrdinatesModel(.1432768641, -.2475000000, .2894649969));
        cordinateList.add(new CoOrdinatesModel(.1433674949, -.2474093692, .2895072588));
        cordinateList.add(new CoOrdinatesModel(.1433674949, -.2475000000, .2894649969));
        cordinateList.add(new CoOrdinatesModel(.1433674949, -.1500000000, .3349299939));
        cordinateList.add(new CoOrdinatesModel(.1433674949, -.3450000000, .2440000000));
        cordinateList.add(new CoOrdinatesModel(.0224000000, -.2137500000, 0.000000));
        cordinateList.add(new CoOrdinatesModel(.0225000000, -.2136500000, 0.000000));
        cordinateList.add(new CoOrdinatesModel(.0225000000, -.2137500000, 0.000000));
//        cordinateList.add(new CoOrdinatesModel(.0224000000, -.0862500000f, 0.000000f));
//        cordinateList.add(new CoOrdinatesModel(.0225000000, -.0861500000f, 0.000000f));
//        cordinateList.add(new CoOrdinatesModel(.0225000000f, -.0862500000f, 0.000000f));
//        cordinateList.add(new CoOrdinatesModel(.5775000000f, .3451000000f, 0.000000f));
//        cordinateList.add(new CoOrdinatesModel(.5776000000f, .3450000000f, 0.000000f));
//        cordinateList.add(new CoOrdinatesModel(.5775000000f, .3450000000f, 0.000000f));
//        cordinateList.add(new CoOrdinatesModel(.8999000000f, -.3225000000f, 0.000000f));
//        cordinateList.add(new CoOrdinatesModel(.9000000000f, -.3224000000f, 0.000000f));
//        cordinateList.add(new CoOrdinatesModel(.9000000000f, -.3225000000f, 0.000000f));
//        cordinateList.add(new CoOrdinatesModel(.8999000000f, -0.000000f, 0.000000f));
//        cordinateList.add(new CoOrdinatesModel(.9000000000f, .001000000f, 0.000000f));
//        cordinateList.add(new CoOrdinatesModel(.9000000000f, -0.000000f, 0.000000f));
//        cordinateList.add(new CoOrdinatesModel(-.0111792893f, .0113207107f, 0.000000f));
//        cordinateList.add(new CoOrdinatesModel(-.0111792893f, .0111792893f, 0.000000f));
//        cordinateList.add(new CoOrdinatesModel(-.0112500000f, .0112500000f, 0.000000f));
//        cordinateList.add(new CoOrdinatesModel(.0225000000f, -.0225000000f, 0.000000f));
//        cordinateList.add(new CoOrdinatesModel(-.0113207107f, -.3111792893f, 0.000000f));
//        cordinateList.add(new CoOrdinatesModel(-.0111792893f, -.3111792893f, 0.000000f));
//        cordinateList.add(new CoOrdinatesModel(-.0112500000f, -.3112500000f, 0.000000f));
//        cordinateList.add(new CoOrdinatesModel(.0225000000f, -.2775000000f, 0.000000f));
//        cordinateList.add(new CoOrdinatesModel(.3525707107f, -.0524292893f, 0.000000f));
//        cordinateList.add(new CoOrdinatesModel(.3525707107f, -.0525707107f, 0.000000f));
//        cordinateList.add(new CoOrdinatesModel(.3525000000f, -.0525000000f, 0.000000f));
//        cordinateList.add(new CoOrdinatesModel(.4275707107f, .1725707107f, 0.000000f));
//        cordinateList.add(new CoOrdinatesModel(.4275707107f, .1724292893f, 0.000000f));
//        cordinateList.add(new CoOrdinatesModel(.4275000000f, .1725000000f, 0.000000f));
//        cordinateList.add(new CoOrdinatesModel(.2362500000f, -.1499000000f, 0.000000f));
//        cordinateList.add(new CoOrdinatesModel(.2363500000f, -.1500000000f, 0.000000f));
//        cordinateList.add(new CoOrdinatesModel(.2362500000f, -.1500000000f, 0.000000f));
//        cordinateList.add(new CoOrdinatesModel(.0225000000f, -.1500000000f, 0.000000f));
//        cordinateList.add(new CoOrdinatesModel(.7499292893f, .1500707107f, 0.000000f));
//        cordinateList.add(new CoOrdinatesModel(.7500707107f, .1500707107f, 0.000000f));
//        cordinateList.add(new CoOrdinatesModel(.7500000000f, .1500000000f, 0.000000f));
//        cordinateList.add(new CoOrdinatesModel(.7500707107f, -.1499292893f, 0.000000f));
//        cordinateList.add(new CoOrdinatesModel(.7500707107f, -.1500707107f, 0.000000f));
//        cordinateList.add(new CoOrdinatesModel(.7500000000f, -.1500000000f, 0.000000f));
//        cordinateList.add(new CoOrdinatesModel(.9000000000f, -.3000000000f, 0.000000f));
//        cordinateList.add(new CoOrdinatesModel(.4275000000f, -.349000000f, 0.000000f));
//        cordinateList.add(new CoOrdinatesModel(.4276000000f, -.3450000000f, 0.000000f));
//        cordinateList.add(new CoOrdinatesModel(.4275000000f, -.3450000000f, 0.000000f));
//        cordinateList.add(new CoOrdinatesModel(.9000000000f, -.3450000000f, 0.000000f));
//        cordinateList.add(new CoOrdinatesModel(.5249292893f, -.0749292893f, 0.000000f));
//        cordinateList.add(new CoOrdinatesModel(.5250707107f, -.0749292893f, 0.000000f));
//        cordinateList.add(new CoOrdinatesModel(.5250000000f, -.0750000000f, 0.000000f));
//        cordinateList.add(new CoOrdinatesModel(.6000000000f, -0.000000f, 0.000000f));
//        cordinateList.add(new CoOrdinatesModel(.4500000000f, -.1500000000f, 0.000000f));
//        cordinateList.add(new CoOrdinatesModel(.8999000000f, .3225000000f, 0.000000f));
//        cordinateList.add(new CoOrdinatesModel(.9000000000f, .3226000000f, 0.000000f));
//        cordinateList.add(new CoOrdinatesModel(.9000000000f, .3225000000f, 0.000000f));
//        cordinateList.add(new CoOrdinatesModel(.9000000000f, .3000000000f, 0.000000f));
//        cordinateList.add(new CoOrdinatesModel(.9000000000f, .3450000000f, 0.000000f));
//        cordinateList.add(new CoOrdinatesModel(-.0451000000f, -.1500000000f, 0.000000f));
//        cordinateList.add(new CoOrdinatesModel(-.0450000000f, -.1499000000f, 0.000000f));
//        cordinateList.add(new CoOrdinatesModel(-.0450000000f, -.1500000000f, 0.000000f));
//        cordinateList.add(new CoOrdinatesModel(-.0450000000f, -.3450000000f, 0.000000f));
//        cordinateList.add(new CoOrdinatesModel(.0524000000f, -.1500000000f, 0.000000f));
//        cordinateList.add(new CoOrdinatesModel(.0525000000f, -.1499000000f, 0.000000f));
//        cordinateList.add(new CoOrdinatesModel(.0525000000f, -.1500000000f, 0.000000f));
//        cordinateList.add(new CoOrdinatesModel(.0525000000f, -.0525000000f, 0.000000f));
//        cordinateList.add(new CoOrdinatesModel(.0525000000f, -.2475000000f, 0.000000f));
//        cordinateList.add(new CoOrdinatesModel(.2549000000f, .1950000000f, 0.000000f));
//        cordinateList.add(new CoOrdinatesModel(.2550000000f, .1951000000f, 0.000000f));
//        cordinateList.add(new CoOrdinatesModel(.2550000000f, .1950000000f, 0.000000f));
//        cordinateList.add(new CoOrdinatesModel(.2550000000f, .3450000000f, 0.000000f));
//        cordinateList.add(new CoOrdinatesModel(.1050000000f, .0451000000f, 0.000000f));
//        cordinateList.add(new CoOrdinatesModel(.1051000000f, .0450000000f, 0.000000f));
//        cordinateList.add(new CoOrdinatesModel(.1050000000f, .0450000000f, 0.000000f));
//        cordinateList.add(new CoOrdinatesModel(.2550000000f, .0450000000f, 0.000000f));
//        cordinateList.add(new CoOrdinatesModel(-.0450000000f, .0450000000f, 0.000000f));
//        cordinateList.add(new CoOrdinatesModel(.0225000000f, -.2775000000f, 2.754757671f));
//        cordinateList.add(new CoOrdinatesModel(.0225000000f, -.0225000000f, 2.754757671f));
//        cordinateList.add(new CoOrdinatesModel(.4500000000f, -.1500000000f, 3.349299939f));
//        cordinateList.add(new CoOrdinatesModel(.0525000000f, -.2475000000f, 2.894649969f));
//        cordinateList.add(new CoOrdinatesModel(.9000000000f, -.3450000000f, 2.440000000f));
//        cordinateList.add(new CoOrdinatesModel(.9000000000f, -.300000000f, 2.649838447f));
//        cordinateList.add(new CoOrdinatesModel(.6000000000f, -0.000000f, 4.048761430f));
//        cordinateList.add(new CoOrdinatesModel(.0525000000f, -.0525000000f, 2.894649969f));
//        cordinateList.add(new CoOrdinatesModel(.9000000000f, .3450000000f, 2.440000000f));
//        cordinateList.add(new CoOrdinatesModel(-.0450000000f, -.3450000000f, 2.440000000f));
//        cordinateList.add(new CoOrdinatesModel(.9000000000f, .3000000000f, 2.649838447f));
//        cordinateList.add(new CoOrdinatesModel(.0225000000f, -.1500000000f, 3.349299939f));
//        cordinateList.add(new CoOrdinatesModel(.2550000000f, .3450000000f, 2.440000000f));
//        cordinateList.add(new CoOrdinatesModel(.2550000000f, .0450000000f, 2.440000000f));
//        cordinateList.add(new CoOrdinatesModel(-.0450000000f, .0450000000f, 2.440000000f));
//        cordinateList.add(new CoOrdinatesModel(0.000000f, -.3000000000f, 2.440000000f));
//        cordinateList.add(new CoOrdinatesModel(.9000000000f, -.3000000000f, 2.440000000f));
//        cordinateList.add(new CoOrdinatesModel(.9000000000f, .3000000000f, 2.440000000f));
//        cordinateList.add(new CoOrdinatesModel(.3000000000f, .3000000000f, 2.440000000f));
//        cordinateList.add(new CoOrdinatesModel(.3000000000f, 0.000000f, 2.440000000f));
//        cordinateList.add(new CoOrdinatesModel(0.000000f, 0.000000f, 2.440000000f));


        List<Double> vList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < cordinateList.size(); i++) {
            vList.add(cordinateList.get(i).getxAxis());
            vList.add(cordinateList.get(i).getyAxis());
            vList.add(cordinateList.get(i).getzAxis());
        }

        Double[] vertexlist = new Double[vList.size()];
        int count = 0;
        for (Double f : vList) {
            vertexlist[count++] = f;
        }

        ByteBuffer vbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertexlist.length * 4);
        vbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        mVertexBuffer = vbb.asDoubleBuffer();
        mVertexBuffer.put(vertexlist);
        mVertexBuffer.position(0);

        // Set triangle border buffer with vertex indices
        short trigborderindexlist[] = {
//                89, 78,
//                79, 89,
//                78, 81,
//                90, 86,
//                83, 82,
//                88, 83,
//                92, 79,
//                87, 78,
//                79, 85,
//                91, 80,
//                90, 84,
//                89, 80,
//                88, 84,
//                83, 84,
//                82, 87,
//                80, 84,
//                86, 88,
//                87, 92,
//                81, 85,
//                91, 90,
//                92, 91,
//                98, 97,
//                93, 98,
//                94, 93,
//                95, 94,
//                96, 95,
//                97, 96

                1,2,2,3,4,5


        };
        mNumOfTriangleBorderIndices = trigborderindexlist.length;
        ByteBuffer tbibb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(trigborderindexlist.length * 2);
        tbibb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        mTriangleBorderIndicesBuffer = tbibb.asShortBuffer();
        mTriangleBorderIndicesBuffer.put(trigborderindexlist);
        mTriangleBorderIndicesBuffer.position(0);
    }

    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
        float x = e.getX();
        float y = e.getY();
        switch (e.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                float dx = x - mPreviousX;
                float dy = y - mPreviousY;
                mAngleY = (mAngleY + (int) (dx * TOUCH_SCALE_FACTOR) + 360) % 360;
                mAngleX = (mAngleX + (int) (dy * TOUCH_SCALE_FACTOR) + 360) % 360;
                break;

        }
        mPreviousX = x;
        mPreviousY = y;
        return true;
    }
//    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
//        switch (e.getAction()) {
//            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
//                pointers = 1;
//                return true;
//            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_2_DOWN:
//                pointers = 2;
//                distance = fingerDist(e);
//                return true;
//            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
//                if (pointers == 2) {
//                    float newDist = fingerDist(e);
//                    float d = distance / newDist;
//                    renderListener.setZoomValue(d);
//                    //
//                    distance = newDist;
//
//                }
//                return true;
//            default:
//                return false;
//        }
//    }

    protected final float fingerDist(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
        float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
        return FloatMath.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
    }

    interface RenderListener {
        void setZoomValue(float d);
    }

}
```

I want to set the float value to the CoOrdinatesModel

Comment: if you want the same result `1432.768641f` then why need conversion ?

Comment: but in adding vertices for the shapes in opengl it needs in this format

Answer (score 0):

Try using double instead of float to preserve the decimal precision.

```
Double xAxis = Double.parseDouble(str);
```

[Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11825877/799844) also, it would be helpful for you to understand

Comment: I could but unfortunately in open gl ByteBuffer's object.asFloatBuffer() doesnot work with double

Comment: not sure what you are trying to achieve (cannot guess without looking at the code) but why don't you use asDoubleBuffer()

Comment: ByteBuffer vbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertexlist.length * 4);
        vbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        mVertexBuffer = vbb.asDoubleBuffer();
        mVertexBuffer.put(vertexlist);//here it shows error
        mVertexBuffer.position(0);

Comment: mVertexBuffer is still of type FloatBuffer in the code above

Comment: ya I've changed it to DoubleBuffer but still not worked so I've share the previous code. any solution ? I'm to upset :(

Comment: if I change to DoubleBuffer then I m getting error in
 mVertexBuffer.put(vertexlist);

it says cannot resolve method put('java.lang.Double[]')

Comment: You would have to change the reference from float to double in your code. For eg. Vertexlist is also of type float

Comment: When you change vertexlist from float [] to double[] .. do you still get the same error message ?

Comment: Use exactly the same  double[] vertexlist = new double[vList.size()];

Comment: voilla !!! thats worked but app crashes and crashes point shows in this place
mVertexBuffer.put(vertexlist);

BufferOverflowException

Comment: The reason why your code is not working is due to fact your are using Double object [] but what doublebuffer expects is primitive type i.e. double []

Comment: What is the exception in logcat?

Comment: here is logcat exception
Process: com.view9.stoddart, PID: 9062
    java.nio.BufferOverflowException
            at java.nio.Buffer.checkPutBounds(Buffer.java:189)
            at java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.put(DirectByteBuffer.java:320)
            at java.nio.ByteBufferAsDoubleBuffer.put(ByteBufferAsDoubleBuffer.java:161)
            at java.nio.DoubleBuffer.put(DoubleBuffer.java:386)
            at

Comment: com.view9.stoddart.opengl.StoddartRenderer.setAllBuffers(StoddartRenderer.java:205)
            at com.view9.stoddart.opengl.StoddartRenderer.onSurfaceCreated(StoddartRenderer.java:72)
            at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1509)
            at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1248)

Comment: Check the size of vbb.asDoubleBuffer(); and vertexlist. Most likely that would be the cause

Comment: ByteBuffer vbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertexlist.length * 8);
that was because of this I set 4 earlier and changed to 8 for double it worked. Thanks bro again u saved my ass

Comment: its not drawing any shapes now bro. :(

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `Float` has finite [precision](http://www.cygnus-software.com/papers/comparingfloats/comparingfloats.htm). You can try using double. Check this:

```
        String str = "1432.768641f";
        float xAxis = Float.valueOf(str);
        System.out.println(xAxis);

        double xAxisD = Double.valueOf(str);
        System.out.println(xAxisD);
```

It prints:

> 1432.7687
>
> 1432.768641

Now why so?
A float is 4 byte whereas double is 8 bytes. A double has more precision and less rounding errors. The following excerpt is taken from this excellent [link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html):

> Squeezing infinitely many real numbers into a finite number of bits
> requires an approximate representation. Although there are infinitely
> many integers, in most programs the result of integer computations can
> be stored in 32 bits. In contrast, given any fixed number of bits,
> most calculations with real numbers will produce quantities that
> cannot be exactly represented using that many bits. Therefore the
> result of a floating-point calculation must often be rounded in order
> to fit back into its finite representation. This rounding error is the
> characteristic feature of floating-point computation.

Comment: I could but unfortunately in open gl ByteBuffer's object.asFloatBuffer() doesnot work with double

Comment: convert string to double first, then again convert to float from double. so that you can eliminate the 'f' which u cant convert from string to float