# I'm having trouble implementing decimal point in my calculator

Tags: java

Between lines 201 and 208 I'm trying to make the decimal point. After the decimal is made, making any calculation the code crashes.

```
JButton btnsum = new JButton("=");
btnsum.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        num2 = Integer.parseInt(textField.getText());

        switch(operator) {
        case 1: result = num1 / num2;
        break;
        case 2: result = num1 * num2;
        break;
        case 3: result = num1 - num2;
        break;
        case 4: result = num1 + num2;
        break;
        case 5: result = Math.pow(num1,num2);
        break;


        default: result = 0.0;
            }

        textField.setText(""+result);
}
});


JButton btncol = new JButton(".");
    btncol.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String str = textField.getText();
            str += (".");
            textField.setText(str);

        }
});
```

Everything else is fine and dandy but this decimal point is not working.

Comment: You're currently using `Integer.parseInt` to parse the number - that's not going to work when you're trying to parse (say) "2.5". I would suggest considering parsing as a `BigDecimal`.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with this line `Integer.parseInt(textField.getText());`

You can parse to `Float` or `Double` and then calculate/process.

But problem in `Float` and `Double` is **Possible Loss of Precision.** for more info on this, you could read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11825865/6446770)

To avoid that precision loss, you can use `BigDecimal` in Java. But working with `BigDecimal` might get complex for you if you haven't used that before. 
But you'll learn more about machine and their processing behavior for sure.

### Note:

Systems where precision really matters like Banking Application, Monetary Calculations, etc, you must use `BigDecimal` for **more** accurate result.